# Drush @sites alias does not work in a multisite installation

Tags: drush, multi-sites

I have 3 Drupal sites installed and I've developed a simple "hello-world" command that just does the following:

```
drush_log(getmypid() . ' Hello world!', 'ok');
```

When I run `drush @sites hello-world` I get the following error message:

> Could not find a Drupal settings.php file at sites/default/settings.php

Please note that the command is working fine when run for a specific site.

```
drush -l test1 hello-world
```

I was under the assumption that Drush @sites alias should be available by default. Is it not?

Comment: I presume from your second example that you have set your --root, perhaps implicitly via `cd /path/to/drupal`. @sites should work as you have described.  What version of Drush are you using?  Please try again with today's master, and file a bug if it's still not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this on HEAD of today's master branch of drush, and `drush @sites status` worked fine for me with no `sites/default` folder.  Try upgrading to drush 7.0-alpha9.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a site at `sites/default` or do you only have 3 subsites that are in 3 other folders?

`@sites` (i believe) makes certain assumptions. Such as "there is a default site directory" and others ... If your site folders are structured otherwise then you need to something like:

`drush @test1 hello-world`

Also note that aliases are defined in [Drush Site Alias files](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php). So for example my `@test1` alias would need to be defined previously for drush.